# MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException:web app connected to Azure SQL Db has been restarted and user accesses it without previously signing out

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-ad-msal, .net-5

I am building a Razor app using Net5.0 and Microsoft.Identity.Web. The app has delegated permission for user impersonation with Azure SQL. Admin consent has been granted in Azure AD.

I've noticed that after I restart the app, if the user has not been signed out or the browser cache cleared the app throws the following error:

> 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException'
> occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user
> code: 'IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a
> challenge for the user. See
> https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent. '  Inner exceptions
> found, see $exception in variables window for more details.  Innermost
> exception      Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException : No
> account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.

I have read the post on Incremental Consent, have decorated my PageModels as described but the only thing that prevents the error from recurring is clearing the browser cache or singing the user out then in again.

The pertinent elements in my Startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            // Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd")
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new[]{"https://database.windows.net//.default"})

                // Adds the User and App InMemory Token Cache 
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            services.AddDbContext<MyDatabaseContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyAzureConnection")));

            services.AddScoped<ITodos, TodoData>();
            
            services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        }
```

My connection string: `"MyAzureConnection": "Server=tcp:MYSERVER.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MYDATABASE;"`

a sample PageModel

```
    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "AzureSQL:BaseUrl")]

    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ITodos _todos;
        
        public IndexModel(ITodos todos)
        {
            _todos = todos;
        }

        public IList<Todo> Todo { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Todo = await _todos.GetToDos();
        }
    }
```

**What I have tried**

I've tried forcing it to refresh the token from the cache with TokenAcquisitionOptions (below)

```
        public AppDbContext(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
                            ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition,
                            DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            :base(options)
        {
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
            _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;

            var user = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
            string[] scopes = new[]{"https://database.windows.net//.default"};
            var connection = (SqlConnection)Database.GetDbConnection();

            TokenAcquisitionOptions tao = new TokenAcquisitionOptions();
            tao.Claims = user.Claims.ToString();
            tao.ForceRefresh = true;

            var result = _tokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(
                                    scopes,"TENANT ID HERE",null,user, tao)
                            .GetAwaiter()
                            .GetResult();
            connection.AccessToken = result.AccessToken;
```

Just requesting the access token for the user, with just scopes and with the additional parameters above

```
            var result = _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes)
                            .GetAwaiter()
                            .GetResult();
```

And when I use `GetAccessTokenForAppAsync`it fails

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred
> in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll but was not handled in
> user code: 'Login failed for user ''.'

I really don't know how to get past this. As long as I clear my browser cache or sign out after it's been restarted I can access the app fine.